# Matching user input to file records in Python

Tags: python

i'm making a program that will ask a user to enter their student ID and it will display the student information such as student ID and their student name . i does this first by asking the user to enter their id and it will then read a .txt file and check if the student id is a matched then it will print out the content of my .txt file information of the specific student that the user is looking for.

this is my content of the file

```
201707001 Michael_Tan 
201707002 Richard_Lee_Wai_Yong 
201707003 Jean_Yip 
201707004 Mark_Lee 
201707005 Linda_Wong 
201707006 Karen_Tan 
201707007 James_Bond 
201707008 Sandra_Smith 
201707009 Paul_Garcia
201707010 Donald_Lim
```

this is my source code

```
# user can find out the student info
userInput = input("Please enter a student ID: ")

# read the students file
with open('C:\\Users\\jaspe\\Desktop\\PADS Assignment\\Student.txt') as f:
    studentFile = f.readlines()
    for student in studentFile:
        stdId, stdName = student.strip().split(" ",1)


# check if the student exist
matched = True

while matched:
    if userInput == stdId:
        print("True")
    else:
        print("False")
        matched = False
        break
```

but the output i get is false even though i type the exact studentID

Comment: Seeing as the problem asks for student information, I assume you are one, and this is homework. Excuse me if that is not the case. But if so, please go to your professor before asking a question on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should perform your checks as you read your file. Otherwise, you are splitting and obtaining your information, but this data is lost in the subsequent iteration. Try this:

```
with open('C:\\Users\\jaspe\\Desktop\\PADS Assignment\\Student.txt') as f:
    studentFile = f.readlines()
    for student in studentFile:
        stdId, stdName = student.strip().split()
        if userInput == stdId:
            print(stdName)
            break
```

---

Better still, for large files, iterate line-wise. Do not use `f.readlines` because it loads all your data into memory.

```
with open('C:\\Users\\jaspe\\Desktop\\PADS Assignment\\Student.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        stdId, stdName = line.strip().split()
        if userInput == stdId:
            print(stdName)
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

As it stands your code loops through every ID and name and assigns each into the `stdId` and `stdName`, but that loop exits before you check for a match... Because of that it only holds the last value stored in those variables by the loop. You need the check in the loop, as so

```
# user can find out the student info
userInput = input("Please enter a student ID: ")

# read the students file
with open('C:\\Users\\jaspe\\Desktop\\PADS Assignment\\Student.txt') as f:
    studentFile = f.readlines()
    for student in studentFile:
        stdId, stdName = student.strip().split(" ",1)
        # check for a match here, break the loop if a match is found
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `raw_input` instead of `input`.

You almost never want to use `input`, because it does evaluation.  In this case, typing in an exact integer gives you an integer, while the file gives you a string, so it won't match.

You have other minor / major issues in the code.

- If the loop is entered with `userInput == stdId` you will loop forever printing `True`.
- You never actually search through the student ids, you just check the last one set in your previous loop

  - (For this I would recommend using a dictionary if you plan to do multiple user queries, or just look as you read the lines of the file for a simple script)

Comment: Any reason for the downvote?  I should note I answered the generic version rather than doing the work because of this line that indicates it is an exact homework assignment (not a generic question): `C:\\Users\\jaspe\\Desktop\\PADS Assignment\\Student.txt`